# Setting up Ogre3d an Qt5.0

Tags: qt, sdk, ogre3d, setting, installation

Im trying to compile a ogre 3d example project on Qt5.0 as a plain c++ project, but Im getting a lot of errors of "No such file or directory", I already add all the paths to the pro file. Also I set the Environment Variable, OGRE_HOME as in this tutorial http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Installing+the+Ogre+SDK .

Can someone help with all steps to make functional Ogre3d SDK on QT5 please Im a beginner.

Im using OgreSDK_vc10_v1-8-1, Mingw 4.7 and QT5.

I followed this steps of a tutorial.

1. Create a new empty project.
2. Create a new file for the code and name it main.cpp.
3. Add the main function:

   ```
   int main (void)
   {
     return 0;
   }
   ```
4. Include ExampleApplication.h at the top of the following source file:

   ```
   #include "Ogre\ExampleApplication.h":
   ```
5. Add PathToYourOgreSDK\include\ to the include path of your project.
6. Add PathToYourOgreSDK\boost_1_42 to the include path of your project.
7. Add PathToYourOgreSDK\boost_1_42\lib to your library path.
8. Add a new class to the main.cpp.

   ```
   class Example1 : public ExampleApplication
   {
   public:
     void createScene()
     {
     }
   };
   ```
9. Add the following code at the top of your main function:

   ```
   Example1 app;
   app.go();
   ```
10. Add PathToYourOgreSDK\lib\debug to your library path.
11. Add OgreMain_d.lib to your linked libraries.
12. Add OIS_d.lib to your linked libraries.
13. Compile the project.
14. Set your application working directory to PathToYourOgreSDK\bin\debug.
15. Start the application. You should see the Ogre 3D Setup dialog.

Comment: Also I'm using windows 7

Answer (score 2):

I am beginner too in Ogre, and I recently found this:

http://advancingusability.wordpress.com/2013/03/30/how-to-integrate-ogre3d-into-a-qt5-qml-scene/

Haven't tried yet, but seems promising to me.

Comment: Are you using the mingw version? I think I found the problem. The problem is the cmake and the build.bat file configuration. And I saw the link there are only widgets to use qt gui and ogre3d.But thanks for the help....

Comment: Sorry, I didn't had time to test it. But yes, for my projects I am using mingw version.

Comment: Do you have any problems building your projects? I can`t compile any project with ogre 3D,qt and mingw(I can`t compile even ogre3D samples using only mingw) , canyou help me?